# How to use Terminal API to listen to all terminal commands/output in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, vscode-extensions

I want to listen to terminal output from extension, such as `tsc -w` and catch the moment if the output contains similar text:

> Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.

Or the error exit code or something like that. Is it possible to do with old API or Proposed API?

Tried:

```
terminal.onDidWriteData(data => {
    console.log('onDidWriteData: ', data.trim());
});
```

It just outputs autogenerated rubbish like:

> Windows PowerShell
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is deprecated in insiders edition.  Try using `window.onDidWriteTerminalData`:

```js
window.onDidWriteTerminalData(event => console.log(event.data.trim()))
```

### Reference

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78574

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way. There is an event API - [`window.onDidWriteTerminalData`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/dc6b475be75999e78233f9f6951ef66f18f768ea), however it is a "proposed" API which means it's only in the Insiders version of VSCode and you can't use it in a published extension. Basically you can't use it.

According to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83224#issuecomment-562672164) and [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78502#issuecomment-559835968) although it is "proposed" never going to make it stable due to performance concerns.

As an alternative perhaps you could pipe `tsc -w` through another program that forwards stdout/stderr and listens for the trigger string. When it sees it it can notify your extension through some other means, e.g. writing a file that you watch or some IPC system.

Unfortunately the downside of that approach is that you can no longer associate the terminal with the VSCode instance, so it might not work if you have multiple VSCode instances running.

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, [API: onDidWriteTerminalData event #78502](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78502) is succeeded by [Expose shell integration command knowledge to extensions
#145234](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/145234).

The latest draft of the API is in [src/vscode-dts/vscode.proposed.terminalShellIntegration.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vscode-dts/vscode.proposed.terminalShellIntegration.d.ts). I'd quote it in this answer post, but it keeps changing and it's annoying for me to keep track of it and update this.

You can find related release notes [here in the release notes for VS Code 1.88](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_88#_terminal-shell-integration-api) (where the API is now released in the "proposed" status). It includes a couple of API usage examples.

The relevant proposal file if you want to try this out is [`src/vscode-dts/vscode.proposed.terminalExecuteCommandEvent.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/6de0f2118f5223dd7297919bc6de655fd3eed074/src/vscode-dts/vscode.proposed.terminalExecuteCommandEvent.d.ts). See also https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/using-proposed-api.