# How to read active terminal output in vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to watch vscode builtin terminal output or at least be able to read whole output. This output will be searched against some pattern.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57630371/how-to-use-terminal-api-to-listen-to-all-terminal-output-in-vscode), but mentioned method

```
window.onDidWriteTerminalData
```

appears to be not available at [current api](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Terminal).

How to read terminal output from vscode extension?

Comment: That is a "proposed" API. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/using-proposed-api

Comment: According to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83224#issuecomment-562672164) and [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78502#issuecomment-559835968) it is "proposed" but actually they are never going to make it stable due to performance concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot do in stable version of VSCode. Try `window.onDidWriteTerminalData` API only in Insider version.

For your information, there are several options, not official supported by VSCode.

1. Use node-pty to create and manage the process and then hook it up using `ExtensionTerminalOptions`.
2. Create a process/script that wraps the terminal shell.

reference:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83224

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/dc6b475be75999e78233f9f6951ef66f18f768ea#r53974957